# SVG.js: referenceError SVG is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, svg

I'm trying to draw a SVG with svg.js.
But when the function SVG() gets called, it gives this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: SVG is not defined`
This is my html code:

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>drawer</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>

        <style>
            .img-overlay-wrap {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block; /* <= shrinks container to image size */
                transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
            }

            .img-overlay-wrap img { /* <= optional, for responsiveness */
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            .img-overlay-wrap svg {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="img-overlay-wrap">
            <img src="imgs/5.JPG" width="1200" height="900" alt="" id="myImgId" />
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
            myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I use laravel for this project, so `{{asset('js/app.js'}}` contains the SVG.js module.
`{{asset('js/script.js')}}` is the script with the call to the SVG() function.

Comment: This doesn't help unfortunately